# Enzyme asserting against a prop that is an Element

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to assert against an element that is provided as a prop to a component.

e.g.

```
function ComponentUnderTest() {
  const foo = <span></span>
  return <Bob something={foo} />
}
```

I have tried doing something like:

```
shallow(<ComponentUnderTest />)
  .prop(‘something’)
  .matchesElement(<span></span>)
```

But I get an error similar to:

> (0 , _enzyme.shallow)(...).prop(...).matchesElement is not a function

It is like I need to lift the something prop value into the enzyme wrapper API.

Any ideas on how I could do this and avoid having to tap into the element itself.

Comment: It's not a prop of `<ComponentUnderTest />` but rather of `<Bob />`, isn't it ? That looks like it doesn't find a prop to cast the function on.

Comment: Yeah, I had checked that myself, but it looks like shallow immediately resolves to the first component, in this case being `Bob`. I also tried `shallow(...).find(Bob).first().prop('something')` to be explicit as possible but it yielded the same result.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to actually pass the props to the component you are rendering and check if it finds the given text inside the given element ?

Comment: I think the problem is that `prop('something')` does not return a `ShallowWrapper` (which has `matchesElement` method) but just the object. Do you have a testframework like jest? You could try `expect(shallow(<ComponentUnderTest />).prop('something')).toMatchObject(<span>your symbol</span>);`

Comment: Hey @Ria - yeah you are correct on this. Confirmed by the Enzyme team.  I asked if there was any way to decorate the prop with the API by it isn't possible at the moment.  Your recommendation is good 

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ria's comment above seems correct to me. `.prop(‘something’)` will return the property value for the "something" prop. This property value is not going to be a ShallowWrapper instance (you can check what it actually is by printing `.prop(‘something’)` to the console). Therefore, you get the normal JavaScript error you get when trying to call a function that does not exist (since `.prop(‘something’).matchesElement` will be undefined).

Answer (score 0):

So you can wrap your prop with `shallow` to initialize Shallow Wrapper and assert using its methods like

```
shallow(
    shallow(<ComponentUnderTest />).prop(‘something’)
  )
.matchesElement(<span></span>)
```